# Reduce gap between card view item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing app where I am using CardView with RecyclerView.

I want to reduce the space between two card items. Want to specify the width of cardview.(Don't want to set width to MATCH_PARENT)

below is my code -

I have done trying with `card_view:cardMaxElevation="1dp"`, `card_view:cardElevation="1dp"` and `card_view:contentPadding="-8dp"` but this is not working for me.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

Here is my cardview -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/companyNameCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/logo_yellow_light"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainCardRelative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/full_transparent_color">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/thumbnailRelative"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:background="@color/full_transparent_color">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_job" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnailRelative"
                android:background="@color/full_transparent_color"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is what I am getting

[image]

Comment: You did set the width of the `CardView` to `match_parent`. Just set it to `wrap_content`

Comment: share all adapter view xml file

Comment: Why not set the height dynamically in your Java file?

Comment: @Vucko I tried with wrap_content it wont work.. the gap between two card items are still same

Comment: @TaslimOseni I have tried setting it up with `DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels/7;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels/2;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.card_view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height= height;
        layoutParams.width= width;
        holder.card_view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);`

Comment: Thank you for the help. With some trail and errors I have solution for my problem, I matched the width of cardview with parent layout's width.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both your items in "LinearLayout" to stick them next to each other.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/companyNameCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/logo_yellow_light"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainCardRelative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/full_transparent_color">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnailRelative"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:background="@color/full_transparent_color">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_job" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnailRelative"
            android:background="@color/full_transparent_color"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```